# Refreshing magento 1.9 cache speeds up checkout significantly

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

we have weird issue:
Checkout ttfb after refreshing cache is about 5 seconds
[image]
When we leave site going (production mode, visitors visiting) after day we get to loading time up to 20 seconds, when even more we get times more than 40-50s ttfb.
When one cache is refreshed, time of ttfb will reduce back to "normal" .
For now we refresh one cache, that is even **disabled** to keep loading times bearable. Regular ttfb for cached page (with FPC,ssl) is under 0,3s

Running on VPS with 4x CPU and 4GB ram.

Magento with 4 storeviews 1.9.2.4

Debian with php  5.6.33

+we had tested different checkouts including magento's default, results in same loading times.

Edit: uploaded profiler pics

•product page without cache: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCiTJ.jpg

•checkout with 12hours old cache https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSEm3.jpg

• checkout with refreshed cache https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zCTP.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked with the profiler what part of the site takes a long time to load?

How to enable the profiler: 
https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-enable-the-magento-profiler.html

Comment: Hi, yes but every time just decreases, not exactly visible issue on magento's side rather than servers. I have edited post so you can view profiler screenshots now